# ionic2 Push notification push.on('notification') not getting triggered in ios app

Tags: ios, angular, push-notification, ionic2

Im new to ios , I created an app using ionic2 & angular2 need to integrate push notification , did all the certificate stuff , integrated with FCM ,
But not able to receive notifications.

Below is my code

```
initPushNotification() {
if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  alert('Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not 
  available - Run in physical device');
  return;
}

 const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    senderID: 'testid'
  },
  ios: {
    alert: 'true',
    badge: false,
    sound: 'true'
  },
  windows: {}
};



const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('device token -> ' + data.registrationId);

 });


pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
  alert('message -> ' + data.message);
  //if user using app and push notification comes
  if (data.additionalData.foreground) {

       alert(data.message);
  } else {
    //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
    //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
    //this.nav.push(DetailsPage, { message: data.message });
    alert('Push notification clicked');
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}); 

 pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => alert('Error with Push plugin' + error));
```

In the above code im able to get token using pushObject.on('registration') but  pushObject.on('notification') is not getting triggered .

In xcode I activated push in capabilities. so no issues there ,

Something in FCM  i think im missing , can anybody help

Comment: Have you configured the p12 file on `cloud messaging` tab of your firebase configuration on console?

Comment: yes I did that , i have uploaded the apn certificate to firebase console. but no luck